# Css styling for the 'width' of a submit button on my HTML form will not size properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, forms, form-submit

My css styling for the 'width' of the submit button on my HTML form will not size properly on mobile. It almost seems like it is hitting a threshold and wont get any thinner but will on the desktop browser?

Form  HTML

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">


    <input type="text" name="Email" value="  Enter email address" onfocus="if (this.value=='  Enter email address') this.value='';"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="+" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=submit]{
border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 3.5%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8%;
left: 61%;
height: 3.2%;
border: none;
background: #FF0000;
color: #FFFFFF;
font: 400 1.5em/.75em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
```

}

*Media Query for Iphone 5 example

```
@media screen and (max-width:645px) {


input[type=submit] {
    bottom: 3%;
    width:4.5%;
    font: 300 1em/0.75em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;

}

input[type=text] {
    bottom: 3%;

}
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what I am getting on desktop vs. phone. The Submit button is circular in desktop view but elongated in mobile?
[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC3iY.png)

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZQtK.png)

Comment: post all the code you are trying

Comment: There is a Factor called Responsiveness in css development. Did you tried it also?

Comment: Hi Jesse, it's best practice around here to submit the code you're working on, as well as what you've tried so far. That will allow people to help you better.

Comment: Just included some HTML and CSS, sorry it is my first time submitting a question. Also I added some screen shots of what I a getting on desktop vs. Mobile at same screen widths. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTMLButtonElement have many predefined style options.

In all browsers they are different and changing 'width' is not enough.

Here's a simple css reset for button. You can set your value here.

```
button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: midddle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border:0;
  ouline:0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario default padding is making it blow:

`padding: 0` should resolve the issue